# Cyclone.exe - Unhandled exception

Tags: unhandled-exception

I am not a programmer. I have some software at work that keeps crashing on me.  I used the Visual Studio debugger last time it crashed and found out it was unhandled exceptions.

The first unhandled exception is at 0x0048ADF0 in Cyclone.exe and is an Access violation writing to location 0x00000003.

My research leads me to understand that this is the program trying to write to memory that the process doesn't have permission to.

When running the debug in Visual Studio, after the access violation exception there is a long list of Unhandled exceptions similar to this "...at 0x776C016E (ntdll.dll) in Cyclone.exe: 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully." with different addresses.

Is there any way I can fix this without being a programmer?  Some sort of modification to the app files or settings, or a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. It's not different from asking if you can drive a car without knowing anything about driving.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to report the problem to the person or company who provided it. What you need to do, however, is give them enough information to understand the problem and fix it. This includes:

- what version of their program are you running
- which computer operating system (e.g. Windows) and which version (e.g. 7)
- *precisely* what steps you have to take to make the error occur
- whether you have changed anything recently, e.g. by installing Windows Updates or changing your anti-virus protection
- precise details of any error messages you see, ideally by copy/paste or by providing a screenshot of the erro
- *anything else* you think might help them to help you

Be prepared for them to ask you additional questions, or try some tests to help figure out the cause and a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your research sounds about right but I don't think there is much anyone here can do to help (unless they happen to work on the application).
Your best bet would be to look for a "Help" or an "About" screen and contact the people who wrote it with this information